# Check that the webserver is running, and that there are no firewalls blocking Facebook's crawlers Symfony

Tags: symfony

Symfony [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/612DE.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head prefix="og: https://ogp.me/ns# fb: https://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: https://ogp.me/ns/article#">
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>УБЦТС ТӨХК-аас гэрэлгүй болон  хүчдэлийн уналттай 11802 өрхийн цахилгаан хангамжийг сайжруулсан | tog.mn </title>



    <meta property="og:site_name" content="tog.mn" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="mn_MN" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="УБЦТС ТӨХК-аас гэрэлгүй болон  хүчдэлийн уналттай 11802 өрхийн цахилгаан хангамжийг сайжруулсан"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="&lt;p style=&quot;text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;
    &lt;span style=&quot;font-size: 14px;&quot;&gt;Өнгөрсөн 2016-2018 онд нийслэлийн төвийн дүүргүүд болон Төв аймгийн&amp;nbsp;Баянчандмань, Баян-Өнжүүл, Лүн, Аргалант, Эрдэнэ, Алтанбулаг, Баянчандмань сумын&amp;nbsp;гэр хорооллын&amp;nbsp;нийт&amp;nbsp;11802 өрхийг цахилгаан эрчим хүчинд холбосон.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://tog.mn/index.php/public/newsshow/id/696" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="595109791247965" /> 
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://tog.mn/uploads/news/14e4b5fcac520ce10c8e3dd36024397b3e166eb7.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="http://tog.mn/uploads/news/14e4b5fcac520ce10c8e3dd36024397b3e166eb7.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1500" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="1000" />
```

Comment: http://tog.mn/index.php/public/newsshow/id/696 
This is the site